# How to properly concatenate actions with JS (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build an extension that is supposed to perform 2-3 actions on a webpage.
Particularly, it's supposed to write some text, check a box, and submit the form.

After some testing, I came up with the conclusion that every action performs correctly when ran individually, but I have problems concatenate them.

The extension has been created with extensionizr.com, a site that allows me to download a pre-configured package.

This is my `inject.js`:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
    var readyStateCheckInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (document.readyState === "complete") {
        clearInterval(readyStateCheckInterval);

        if (window.location.hash === '#wannascript') {
            
            // action 1: fill the email field
            document.querySelectorAll('#email-input')[0].value = 'thisisatest12345@zeroreverse.org'

            // action 2: waiting a delay and clicking on the checkbox
            setTimeout(() => {document.querySelectorAll('.AkIi97 > label')[0].click();}, 2000);

            // action 3: clicking on submit
            document.querySelectorAll('body > div:nth-child(10) > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.qMZa55.DgFgr2.VHXqc_.rceRmQ.JUQZbi > div > div > form > div > div > div:nth-child(5) > button')[0].click()
            
        }


    }
    }, 10);
});
```

When I start my extension, it correctly goes to the page, then it fills the email field, waits properly for the delay but then the email field gets reset and the box gets checked.

How do I avoid the "reset" of the email field, and how can I submit the form correctly?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: setTimeout is not a blocking call, it is async meaning the code after it runs while the timeout is waiting to call its callback.

Comment: I added that when I was testing, because  if I just had put `document.querySelectorAll('.AkIi97 > label')[0].click();`, only the box would be checked, there would be nothing in the email field.